# Is there a shorthand for <fmt:message key="key" />?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

It's tedious and ugly to write things like:

```
<input type="button" value="<fmt:message key="submitKey" />" />
```

And in case you want to nest the message tag in another tag's attribute it becomes even worse.

Is there any shorthand for that. For example (like in JSF):

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.shareKey}" />
```

(spring-mvc-only solutions applicable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feels like a bit of a hack, but you could write a custom implementation of `java.util.Map` which, when `get(key)` is called, fetches the message from the Spring `MessageSource`. This `Map` could be added to the model under the `msg` key, allowing you to dereference the messages using `${msg.myKey}`.

Perhaps there's some other dynamic structure than is recognised by JSP EL that isn't a `Map`, but I can't think of one offhand.

```
public class I18nShorthandInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(I18nShorthandInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        request.setAttribute("msg", new DelegationMap(localeResolver.resolveLocale(request)));

        return true;
    }

    private class DelegationMap extends AbstractMap<String, String> {
        private final Locale locale;

        public DelegationMap(Locale locale) {
            this.locale = locale;
        }

        @Override
        public String get(Object key) {
            try {
                return messageSource.getMessage((String) key, null, locale);
            } catch (NoSuchMessageException ex) {
                logger.warn(ex.getMessage());
                return (String) key;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
            // no need to implement this
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

As an alternative:

```
<fmt:message key="key.name" var="var" />
```

Then use `${var}` as a regular EL.

Comment: yes, I thought of something like that, but hoped something ready exists.

Comment: I added the code that implements your answer more or less. If you see something not good in it, please correct it :)

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is a shortcut, you can create a tag file, say btn.tag

```
<%@tag%>
<%@ attribute name="key" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<input type="button" value="<fmt:message key="${key}" />" />
```

And use it like this

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tags"%>
...
<tags:btn key="submitKey" >
...
```

Comment: that's a good idea, but it will require too many tags to re-define. +1 though

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. Since I don't do Spring, I'll leave it out of the context in this answer. For the Spring-targeted answer, see @skaffman. You can create a class which `extends`[`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), manage the loading yourself with help of a `Filter` (based on request path?) and store it in the session scope. The `ResourceBundle` is accessible the usual JSP EL way. You can access it as if it's a `Map`. The [`handleGetObject()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#handleGetObject%28java.lang.String%29) method will be invoked on every access.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class Text extends ResourceBundle {

    private static final String TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "text";
    private static final String TEXT_BASE_NAME = "com.example.i18n.text";

    private Text(Locale locale) {
        setLocale(locale);
    }

    public static void setFor(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, new Text(request.getLocale()));
        }
    }

    public static Text getCurrentInstance(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (Text) request.getSession().getAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        if (parent == null || !parent.getLocale().equals(locale)) {
            setParent(getBundle(TEXT_BASE_NAME, locale));
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return parent.getObject(key);
    }

}
```

The `Filter`:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Text.setFor((HttpServletRequest) request);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

JSP:

```
<p>${text['home.paragraph']}</p>
```

If you want to change the locale from inside some servlet or filter:

```
Text.getCurrentInstance(request).setLocale(newLocale);
```

#### Related/interesting-to-know:

- [Overriding `ResourceBundle#Control` to read files using UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183245/internationalization-in-a-website/2458938#2458938)
- [List all available `ResourceBundle` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685907/list-all-avilable-resourcebundle-files/2686435#2686435)
- [Iterating through multiple properties from `ResourceBundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474027/how-do-i-iterate-through-multiple-properties-in-jsp/2477014#2477014)

Answer (score 0):

I find a way without any interceptor:

```
${pageScope["org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.REQUEST_CONTEXT"]
    .getMessage("hello")}
```

but it's too long, and the key "org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.REQUEST_CONTEXT" may not be compatible for all versions of spring.

Comment: yeah, but that's pretty tedious

Answer (score 0):

I use a properties file for each language, and the following works well:

`<input type="button" value="${msg['myKey']}" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `msg` request variable in a servlet or filter with the resource bundle to get the messages via EL expression in JSP code by this way `${msg.messageKey}`

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

...

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

  String STR_LOCALE = "es-MX"; // you can get this value from the http request to get the default browser locale.
  String LOCALE_BASENAME = "my.package.basename";
  Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(STR_LOCALE);
  req.setAttribute("msg", ResourceBundle.getBundle(LOCALE_BASENAME, locale));

  // And you can setup the 'fmt' tag library from here to resolve parameterized messages.
  Config.set(req, Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
  Config.set(req, Config.FMT_LOCALIZATION_CONTEXT, LOCALE_BASENAME);

}
```

Example:

```
 ...
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
 ...
 <h1>${msg.header}</h1>
 <h2>${msg[variableHeader]}</h2>
 <fmt:message key='messageWithVariable'>
    <fmt:param>The value</fmt:param>
 </fmt:message>
```

---

*This is working in my java servlet 2.5 environment.*