# Is there any way to reduce the verbosity of JSP pages

Tags: jsp, struts

After three years on a RESTful Java/ExtJS application, I have taken over development of a Java/JSP application.

New to Java Struts, I am finding the use of struts tags in JSP pages to be insanely verbose, e.g.

```
<input type="button" value='<bean:message key="button.addDoc"/>' />
```

Of course there are about 1700 message tags in every page, and it would seem that something like $m("button.addDoc") would be quite enough.  Is there some way to shorten the bean:message elements to something less noisy, or is this just the Java way?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174373/is-there-and-shorthand-for-fmtmessage-key-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *or is this just the Java way?*

That's just the Struts way. It's a pretty legacy MVC framework. You could consider to look for a different MVC framework which resolves properties by just EL, for example JSF.

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bundle.addDoc}" />
```

It's only going to be a lot of work with that much pages/tags. Since it's apparently an assignment, I'd just live with it and keep it for the future in mind to deny old Struts based projects.

Comment: note that spring doesn't have s short way as well. Check my comment on the question.

Comment: thanks for the help.  It's not an assignment, it's my sole responsibility for a good while.

Comment: I think my ultimate plan is to move all the JSPs to to Groovy HtmlBuilder.

Comment: You can use EL without moving to JSF.