# Access message source from EL

Tags: java, spring, el

Suppose I have the following message source file:

```
title=foo
somefield=bar
...
```

I always access it in the following way:

```
<fmt:message key="title" />
```

but I'd prefer to use EL instead, something like:

```
${messages.title}
```

Is there a way to use expression language for accessing message source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there and shorthand for <fmt:message key="key" />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174373/is-there-and-shorthand-for-fmtmessage-key-key)

Comment: very good question, but I think I've already asked it :) Check the solution that I applied (it works for me)

Comment: The reason I don't vote for this question to close is to see if there has been a better solution since @Bozho's question. By now Spring should have caught on, or did they? :)

Comment: Answers can just be posted in that duplicate whenever necessary. It's not forbidden to revive old questions with new answers with new ideas/solutions.