# JSP and ResourceBundles

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, internationalization, jstl

Typically resource bundles are loaded and used within a JSP using JSTL and fmt, but this requires to always use the syntax `<fmt:message key=""/>` to access the value.

When the text to be localized looks like
`<a href="url" title="message">` it is awkward (though valid to write):

```
<a href="url" title="<fmt:message key="key"/>">
```

and plain awkward to use the scoped syntax

```
<fmt:message key="key" var="var">
<a href="url" title="${var}"> 
</fmt:message>
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I am looking for something like just

```
<a href="url" title="${messages.key}">
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why does using <fmt> sound so 'awkward' to you. If you want something of the format as you mentioned above, then you can define your own `messages` bean and handle localization within it, such that you return the value from the appropriate resource bundle (as per the user's locale).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174373/is-there-and-shorthand-for-fmtmessage-key-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Yes, the below is a copy of my answer at [Is there a shorthand for <fmt:message key="key" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174373/is-there-and-shorthand-for-fmtmessage-key-key) as mentioned in Bozho's comment on your question. But since that question is actually Spring-targeted, my answer wasn't fully applicable there. Your question is however not Spring-targeted, but just plain JSP/Servlet targeted and can therefore not be closed as exact dupe. So I think the answer is better at its place here:*</sub>

---

You can create a class which `extends`[`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), manage the loading yourself with help of a `Filter` (based on request path?) and store it in the session scope. The `ResourceBundle` is accessible the usual JSP EL way. You can access it as if it's a `Map`. The [`handleGetObject()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#handleGetObject%28java.lang.String%29) method will be invoked on every access.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
package com.example.i18n;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class Text extends ResourceBundle {

    private static final String TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "text";
    private static final String TEXT_BASE_NAME = "com.example.i18n.text";

    private Text(Locale locale) {
        setLocale(locale);
    }

    public static void setFor(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, new Text(request.getLocale()));
        }
    }

    public static Text getCurrentInstance(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (Text) request.getSession().getAttribute(TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        if (parent == null || !parent.getLocale().equals(locale)) {
            setParent(getBundle(TEXT_BASE_NAME, locale));
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return parent.getObject(key);
    }

}
```

*(note the `TEXT_BASE_NAME` constant should refer to name of the resource bundle files, the above example assumes that you've `text.properties`, `text_en.properties`, etc in the `com.example.i18n` package)*

The `Filter`:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Text.setFor((HttpServletRequest) request);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

JSP:

```
<p>${text['home.paragraph']}</p>
```

If you want to change the locale from inside some servlet or filter:

```
Text.getCurrentInstance(request).setLocale(newLocale);
```

#### Related/interesting-to-know:

- [Overriding `ResourceBundle#Control` to read files using UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183245/internationalization-in-a-website/2458938#2458938)
- [List all available `ResourceBundle` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685907/list-all-avilable-resourcebundle-files/2686435#2686435)
- [Iterating through multiple properties from `ResourceBundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474027/how-do-i-iterate-through-multiple-properties-in-jsp/2477014#2477014)
- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Comment: Note that using 'new Text(request.getLocale())' you lose the caching feature and the resource bundle will be reloaded in each request

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you may need to create and register your own [`ELResolver`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html). Take a look at this answer - [Alternative to using c:out to prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465583/alternative-to-using-cout-to-prevent-xss#4466987).

So you might reserve a prefix such as `MESSAGES` and translate that into a `ResourceBundle` lookup.

i.e. `${MESSAGES.key}` gets processed by your `ELResolver` as `bundle.getString(key)`.